# Why TableView added invisible separator on some rows?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

This separator is invisible on normal view. I set all separator layer to red and had seen it. If I set `tableView.separatorStyle = .none`, this separator, and normal separator not added to cell. Easy to reproduce:

1. Add TableViewController
2. Set cell [image]
3. Add code to cell:

   ```
   override func layoutSubviews() {
       super.layoutSubviews()
       let separators = self.subviews.filter({$0.bounds.height < 1 && $0.bounds.height > 0})
       separators.forEach({
           $0.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
       })
   ```

What is it?

Comment: Did you also tried to test on a real device?

Comment: You will not get the issue in real device, or another way is to make your simulator screen bigger (cmd+1)

Comment: yes, it's reproduce for iPhone 7 ( iOS 10.2.1 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I understand. These invisible views are not separators, they are created when I make my margins is relative.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way for replace the separator, or show it in some way or show one different for each section is this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 1:
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 0.0, 0);
            let additionalSeparatorThickness = CGFloat(1)
            let additionalSeparator: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 15.0, y: cell.frame.size.height - additionalSeparatorThickness,
                                                                   width: cell.frame.size.width-30.0,
                                                                   height: additionalSeparatorThickness))
            additionalSeparator.backgroundColor = UIColor.Red
            cell.addSubview(additionalSeparator)
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

In the sample above(with some customization for the line width, height, ecc), for all the rows in the section 1 we draw a red line separator and in the other sections we don't show anything.

Comment: I think separator height is 0.5 is it? Sorry but it's not answer for my question, I set color for looking invisible line. Thanks